# After Installing 14.04 LTS on blank hard drive successfuly, it won't boot at all

Tags: boot

After what seems to be a successful installation and restart, I get the message "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".  I have made sure the boot order is correct and have disabled secure boot.  I am not sure what to do next.  I am currently in UEFI boot mode with a CSM boot mode option as well.  What should I try next, or what am I possibly doing wrong?

This hard drive came with Windows 8.  I then dual booted it with 14.04 successfully.  It worked like a charm.  Then I decided to go to just Ubuntu on the hard drive.  I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with my bootable flash drive (the same one I dual booted with) and deleting Windows 8.  That's where my current problem starts.

Comment: At what stage does it fail?  What message do you get?

Comment: It seems to never even start as I hit the power button and the message "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key" immediately appears on screen

Comment: That message means that your system's boot ROM (BIOS or UEFI) isn't finding a bootable medium among the drives it searches on startup.  You may be able to perform a boot repair from your Ubuntu Live media; otherwise, I suspect you're down to reinstalling Ubuntu.  Um, you do have a 64-bit or UEFI-specific Ubuntu download, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at answering anything on here, so take this with a grain of salt. Let me ask this first and I or someone more knowledgeable can go from there. Have you gone into your motherboard BIOS and configured the boot order of drives so that the one you want to boot from is first in line or first after your CD/DVD drive? Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried that with the same result

Comment: Hamharry: Any other ideas???  @ThomasH: does this still persist?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this 3 years after the question has been asked because I did the same but the issue is the same with any new distro like 18.04.
The problem is when you deleted windows you also deleted a partition that the uefi boot process needs. It's a small ntfs partition, something like 10Mb usually partition nr 1.
Don't delete this partition. Delete the big one. partition nr 2
I fixed it by copying that partition from an identical computer but if you don't have that just reinstall windows to the point that it boots and then boot with your linux stick and delete the big ntfs partition and leave the small one.